# Why doesn't Siri call a contact that it clearly understands?

Tags: ios, siri, contacts.app

I have a contact entry with no first name and a last name of "Charles Schwab Customer Service". When I tell Siri "Call Charles Schwab Customer Service", it shows the words on the screen exactly as I've spoken them, so it clearly understands what I've said. But instead of calling the contact, it asks, "Call Jones Communication Customer Service on 336 Post Office Rd...?" Obviously, Siri doesn't connect what it knows I'm saying to the contact entry I want it to call.

What do I need to do to get Siri to make the call I want it to make?

Comment: Try putting it in the Company name field or in the First Name....other than that, a bug submission to Apple?

Comment: It works in the First Name field, but not in the Company field. Thanks for the suggestion, though I still think it's strange that it doesn't work in the other fields.

Answer (score -1):

when you ask Siri to call a company and it finds the company name on the web Siri gives you what he finds on the web.
try for example to create a contact called Subway than ask Siri to call Subway you will see he looks first on the web.

Comment: Downvoted, because as noted above, putting "Charles Schwab Customer Service" in the First Name field works.